# Google Play Services - The application is incorrectly configured

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am getting an error when trying to login to test my app.

It says : The application is incorrectly configured. Check that the package name and signing certificate match the client ID created in Developer Console. Also, if the application is not yet published, check that the account you are trying to sign in with is listed as a tester account. See logs for more information.

I have verified that the package name and signing certificate match what I entered in the Developer console.  Additionally I verified that the app_id is correct.

I have been googling for hours and cannot seem to find a solution that doesn't involve one of those answers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using any google specific apis? Have you checked your settings on Google api console? I believe your problem is related to a solution given here - https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth but without having additional details its difficult to exactly pinpoint. Hope this link helps.

Comment: I deleted my project on the google play developer console and re-created it. I can't say why it worked but it did. Thanks anyways!